# get all entities using DatastoreService

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to get all entities using DatastoreService on AppEngine in Java? Basically if I do

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
```

What should I do next to get all the entities of a kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a query with no filters:

```
Query q = new Query("person");
for (Entity entity : datastore.prepare(q).asIterable()) {
    // do something with this entity
}
```

Note that if you have more than a 1,000 entities, it's better to read them in chunks. And if you have a very large number of entities, you may need to use a cursor. All of this is explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries).

Comment: Thanks! This maybe a bit cheeky of me but is there a way to do a bulk update? Basically I add a new field to my entity and it is missing. I want to force all my entities to show the field in the datastore. Thanks. I am going to try what you said in the meantime.

Comment: @KatedralPillon: mapreduce will help